# PHP code for parsing Yahoo Weather Info fails for negative degrees

Tags: php, parsing, yahoo

I have the following code to parse Yahoo Weather Info:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=868274&u=c');
    $weatherInfo = $xml->channel->item->description;
    $imagePattern = '/src="(.*?)"/i';
    preg_match($imagePattern, $weatherInfo, $matches);
    $imageSrc = $matches[1];
    $degreesPattern = '/.*?, (\d+) C/i';
    preg_match($degreesPattern, $weatherInfo, $matches);
    $degrees = $matches[1];
echo $degrees;
```

How can I modify the parser in order to work for negative degrees?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the dash optional:

```
$degreesPattern = '/.*?, (-?\d+) C/i';
                          ^^
```

You can see from [this demo](http://viper-7.com/2E5IB4) that it prints:

```
-1
```

Answer (score 1):

this is working good with codeigniter2.1.4 paste to the view file .direct

```
<?php
// weather City qalat-dizah
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=1977965&u=c');
    $weatherInfo = $xml->channel->item->description;
    $imagePattern = '/src="(.*?)"/i';
    preg_match($imagePattern, $weatherInfo, $matches);
    $imageSrc = $matches[1];
     echo img($imageSrc) .'<br/>';
    $degreesPattern = '/.*?, (-?\d+) C/i';
    preg_match($degreesPattern, $weatherInfo, $matches);
    $degrees = $matches[1];
  echo  $degrees .'<br/>';
// end
?>
```